# JSON Array formatting, no column names

Tags: json, sql-server

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95c4db0d481492956af1a2f566359a38

I'm writing a new query for a project, and trying to format the JSON string so that it will give me an array instead of an object in MoreInfo.

I've been able to mess around with the formatting, but can't seem to shake off the Score column label. What's the best way to do this?

```
SELECT TOP (1)
    contacts.PhoneNumber,
    contacts.ContactName,
    MoreInfo.Score
    FROM (SELECT 
        PrimaryPhone as PhoneNumber, 
        FirstName + ' ' + LastName as ContactName,
        callList.Call_Identity
        FROM CallList callList 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts a 
            ON callList.Call_IDENTITY = a.Call_IDENTITY
        ) contacts
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT CAST(Score as varchar) as Score, Call_Identity
        FROM dbo.Contacts contact 
     ) MoreInfo on MoreInfo.Call_Identity = contacts.Call_Identity
    FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Current results:

```
[ 
   { 
      "PhoneNumber":"3172222222",
      "ContactName":"Peyton Manning",
      "MoreInfo":[ 
         { 
            "Score":"0.1",
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm trying to get:

```
[ 
   { 
      "PhoneNumber":"3172222222",
      "ContactName":"Peyton Manning",
      "MoreInfo":["0.1"]
   }
]
```

Comment: Replace `MoreInfo.*` with `MoreInfo.Score` and/or don't use `AUTO`? Difficult for us to test with no sample data.

Comment: 2017 SQL Server: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95c4db0d481492956af1a2f566359a38

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're hugely over complicating your query:

```
SELECT c.PrimaryPhone AS PhoneNumber,
       c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS ContactName,
       c.Score AS MoreInfo
FROM dbo.callList cL --Why is this even here, it's never referenced
     JOIN Contacts C ON cL.Call_IDENTITY = C.Call_Identity
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

This returns the below:

```
[
    {
        "PhoneNumber":"3172222222",
        "ContactName":"Peyton Manning",
        "MoreInfo":0.10
    }
]
```

Comment: callList is used to filter the Contact table. Additionally, I need MoreInfo to be an Array of a string value.

Comment: Pretty sure you won't be able to do that, @JDurling; you'll get the error `Column expressions and data sources without names or aliases cannot be formatted as JSON text using FOR JSON clause. Add alias to the unnamed column or table.
`

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a hack but I think it would technically work for you. Basically you just separate out the array that you're looking for using a string concatenation and then use JSON_Query to have the main query treat it as a JSON value so that it doesn't try to convert it to JSON again.

I did the best I could with the example, it's a little difficult to understand the structure of your data.

```
WITH contacts
AS (SELECT Call_Identity = 1, PhoneNumber = '3172222222', ContactName = 'Peyton Manning', Score = 0.1)
SELECT  a.Call_Identity,
    a.PhoneNumber,
    a.ContactName,
    MoreInfo = JSON_QUERY((
                    SELECT  Score = '[' + STRING_AGG( '"' + CAST(Score AS VARCHAR) + '"',',') + ']'
                    FROM    contacts x
                    WHERE  x.Call_Identity = a.Call_Identity
                    GROUP BY Call_Identity

                ) )
FROM contacts a 
FOR JSON AUTO
```